# Read zip file on s3 without download or save in Laravel or PHP

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3, php-ziparchive

I need to get the images file name in a zip file that uploaded to s3 without download or save, is that possible? Currently i'm only able to make it if file are store in local.

here is my code:

```
$z = new ZipArchive();
$url = public_path('storage\\' . $asset->getRawOriginal('path'));

$names = [];
if ($z->open($url)) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < $z->numFiles; $i++) {
        $stat = $z->statIndex($i);
        array_push($names, basename($stat['name']));
    }
}
natsort($names);
$names = array_values($names);
return $names;
```

Is there any method to do so?

Comment: another solution would be to not store it in zip format, just unzip it in a folder on S3.

Comment: @N69S because need to upload 100 of files at the same time, not zipping it seems like not a good options

Comment: You can upload multiple files in a single action using sync.